# 'no matter in which way' or 'no matter which way?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Is *in* necessary in the phrase:

> It is the same, no matter in which way it is done.

That is, is it acceptable to write:

> It is the same, no matter which way it is done.

Comment: Both are relatively clumsy-sounding. Colloquially, you’d be much more likely to hear “no matter _what way_ it’s done”; and both colloquially and more formally, you’d be even more likely to head “no matter _how_ it’s done”, which is both simpler and flows better. (Also, please note that quotes should not be indented as code, but instead prefixed with “>”, which makes blockquotes. I’ve fixed it in your question here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frequent "in which way" is nearly always shortened to "which way".

Comment: Could you expand on that a bit?

Comment: http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=which+way&mysubmit=Go  Not all examples are of the type (in) which way but you can find a lot. Source: BNC British National Corpus. Sometimes other prepositions such as from/on fit as well.